# How to handle a CRC error while extracting a .zip through 7zip command in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, 7zip, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

```
$sourceZip = "Path\Bla.zip\"
$destinationForExtraction = "Anotherpath\Bla"
7z x $sourceZip "-o$destinationForExtraction" *.exe -y
```

This code snippets gives an error `7z : ERROR: CRC Failed: SomeFile.exe`.
I have checked the crc of the above file. Yes the crc doesn't match. But the same zip gets extracted using manual procedure (Right Click > Extract To Folder).

Is there any way to handle this exception?

What's the reason behind these contradicting behaviors of 7z?  It extracts properly while extracting manually but can not extract the same file while extracting through command line.

Comment: If you wish to catch the exception and deal with it then use try/catch.  If u r looking fow why is it so? Then i would suggest u to check other system once or reninstall the 7zip once and see

Comment: That's something you need to ask the author of `7z.exe`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RanadipDutta thanks for your suggestions. I definitely tried with try/catch. But unfortunately PowerShell does not support try/catch in case of External Command. In this case 7z is an external command and not a .NET command, therefore catching the exception using the try/catch is not possible. I tried with $LASTEXIT code but that's also no working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting the error should work for you:

```
$cmdOutput = 7z x $sourceZip "-o$destinationForExtraction" *.exe -y 2>&1
```

***$cmdoutput*** should hold the value now.